# searching pandas for value greater than a number

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following data:

```
    toggle_day  Diff
Date        
2000-01-04  True    NaT
2000-01-11  True    7 days
2000-01-24  True    13 days
2000-01-28  True    4 days
2000-02-09  True    12 days
... ... ...
2019-08-14  True    2 days
2019-08-23  True    9 days
2019-10-01  True    39 days
2019-10-02  True    1 days
2019-10-08  True    6 days
677 rows × 2 columns
```

I want to see the dates when `Diff` is greater than 20 days. To do this i have done something like this: 
`df1[df1.diff > 20 days]` This is wrong, I think because i need to tell it `days` in datetime. I tried `df1[df1.diff > datetime.datetime(20)]` but that does not work either:

> TypeError: function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)

How can i search `Diff` for days greater than a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is compare by timedeltas:

```
df[df['Diff'] > pd.Timedelta(1, 'd')]
```

Or you can convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and compare by number:

```
df[df['Diff'].dt.days > 1]
```

Comment: The second one worked and i think i understand it, the first returned an error `TypeError: Cannot compare type Timedelta with type method`

Comment: @newcoder - I think if use `['col name']` it should working, here `df['Diff']`

Comment: @newcoder - problem should be if column name is `diff`, it is collision with method [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), so `df.diff` raise error

Comment: you are right i changed to `Diff` from`diff` and it worked!